# Silverlight Update Feature, this feels oh so wrong. Where is ReportProgress or a separation between CheckForUpdate() and Update()

Tags: silverlight, auto-update, silverlight-oob

I've created a line of business Out of Browser Application.

I need more control over the update process.

I would like to initiate an updating screen, on start-up when the download of the update has started, and deactivate the app.  But as far as I know, I have no way to tell if the worker is in progress.  Be nice if ReportProgress was available or something similar.  Maybe there is and I'm totally missing it.  Be great if I could do a progress bar based on bytes downloaded.

Right now the only way I can do anything remotely like this, is by waiting a couple seconds, and if the CheckAndDownloadUpdateCompleted event hasn't fired, I know its probably downloading???  Show an intermittent progress bar, and wait for it to complete.  Luckily one of the business requirements is a start-up splash screen.   I'm betting this will work... but man does that just feel ooooh so wrong, there has to be a better way.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope you're not missing anything the `CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync` and its Completed event is the sum total to what passes for an upgrading API in Silverlight.  Sounds like you have a reasonable plan.

You might be interested in the Silverlight Toolkit `BusyIndicator` control. In addition to delivering your progress bar requirement it also has a `DisplayAfter` property which will prevent it displaying for the time specified after its `IsBusy` property is set true.

Comment: Not what I like to hear lol.   But I thank you for the reply.